# Getting Length of Longest Palindrome Subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm

This solution works, but I'm not sure if it can be improved upon. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int arr[] = new int[] {4,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};  
        System.out.println(maxLengthPalindrome(arr, 0, arr.length-1));
    }

    public static int maxLengthPalindrome(int[] values, int i, int j) {
        if(j<=i) 
            return j-i+1;
        if(values[i]==values[j]) 
            return 2 + maxLengthPalindrome(values, i+1, j-1);
        else 
            return Math.max(maxLengthPalindrome(values, i+1, j), maxLengthPalindrome(values, i, j-1));      
    }
}
```

Comment: If your solution works and you're looking for code improvement then go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code improvement and belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: The OP is not looking to *improve this code*, but to *improve upon this solution*. I think that's absolutely on-topic here. (If someone posted asking for a better sorting algorithm, and you see that they've successfully implemented bubblesort, would you send them to codereview.stackexchange.com to learn about mergesort?)

Comment: @ruakh no, I would provide a comment with a link to other algorithm sorts and let OP do the research about it and move on. I don't find a specific programming problem but a code that works and OP looks for improvement, which is totally on topic there, and may or not be may on topic here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: If you think that it "may or [may not be] on topic here", then why did you vote to close it as off-topic? And anyway, the OP basically just needs the two-word answer "dynamic programming", plus a link. That hardly seems like a matter for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Because I think this specific question should be there and not here. But that's my opinion, not everybody need to share it.

Comment: "Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers" - I'm voting to keep closed because of that. What's *wrong* with the code? What's not working? Why would you *think it needs* to be improved upon?

Comment: Longest substring problems are typically `O(N^2)`. Of course you could optimise typical runtime in many ways, using dynamic programming, or rolling hash, or 1D version of A*. The choice of optimisation is based on typical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that it will result in many repeated calls for the exact same subarrays. Consider this sequence:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

You will make recursive calls for these two subarrays:

```
2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
```

which in turn involves recursive calls for these:

```
3 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 4      // duplicate!
1 2 3
```

which in turn involves:

```
4 5
3 4
3 4        // duplicate!
2 3
3 4        // duplicate!
2 3        // duplicate!
2 3        // duplicate!
1 2
```

. . . you see the problem. As a result, the total algorithmic complexity is exponential, O(2<sup>*n*</sup>), even though the total number of distinct calls is just quadratic, O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

A better approach is to use something called *[dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)* (or "bottom-up recursion"): you can use an *n*×*n* array to keep track of the longest palindromic subsequence within each subarray. You start with the "bottom" — store the length of the longest palindromic subsequence in each subarray of length 1, and then proceed to subarrays of length 2, and so on. In each pass, you have the results of all previous passes available for use. There is only one subarray of length *n*, and the answer you want is the length of *its* longest palindromic subsequence.

Note that, for each pass (e.g., subarrays of length *m*), you actually only need the previous two passes (subarrays of length *m*−1 and subarrays of length *m*−2), so you can optimize for space by using two one-dimensional arrays of length *n* rather than one two-dimensional array of size *n*×*n*; however, I don't recommend making that optimization until after you have it working with the *n*×*n* array (since the ability to print out all previous results as a matrix is likely to be helpful for debugging).